# Android JsonReader (Expected a name but was BEGIN_OBJECT)

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get weather data from JSON format from this [JSON code](http://api.wunderground.com/api/89ef283108b7ea38/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json).
And my code to get it is:

```
URL url ;
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
String result ="";
try {
    url=new URL(params[0]);
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(reader);
    jsonReader.beginObject();
    while(jsonReader.hasNext())
    {
        String name = jsonReader.nextName();
        Log.e("jsonname",name);

    }
    jsonReader.endObject();
```

and the log result is

```
jsonnametofaa: response
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was BEGIN_OBJECT
    at android.util.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:390)
    at com.example.tofaa.myapplication.Do.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:92)
    at com.example.tofaa.myapplication.Do.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am not getting the all JSON objects.

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't use `Gson`?

Comment: i am new in android development and i do not know Gson yet

Comment: Have a look at popular libraries to parse JSON such as [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi).

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer for you so.

Comment: Can someone please provide a solution that does not involve a workaround.  I'm actually stuck on the same error while dealing with a complicated JSON hierarchy. I also know that my json begins with an object and not a name.

Answer (score 1):

Imaging it's your JSON response:

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "foo2":"bar2"
}
```

You can parse it like this. First you need to create a Model Class:

**ModelClass.java**

```
public class ModelClass {
    public String foo;
    public String foo2;
}
```

And you can parse it using Gson like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ModelClass instance = gson.fromJson(json, ModelClass.class);
```

And don't forget to add it in your dependency:

`compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'`

Comment: thanks in advance
i will try to find out like this and respond to you